# Как сделать объект "твёрдым" | Баги с картой уровня

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, canvas

Когда-то давно я нашёл, дескать, "самую сложную игру" ( http://caniplay.ru/flash/4565 ), и вот, спустя несколько лет, решил сделать что-то подобное, только не шибко хардкорное.
Дело в том, что столкновения-то я обнаруживать научился, но вот как сделать объект твёрдым при столкновении - это уже посложнее.
Я вообще не понимаю что в коде не так, вроде всё логично, но js так не считает.

Ещё с картой уровня проблемы: верхняя часть съезжает.
Логикой это дело не возьмёшь.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

P.s. только чёткий и ясный ответ, не псевдокод или тупо объяснение с хабра, а именно рабочий пример.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>.</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0">
 <canvas id="can" style="display: block"></canvas>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function getId(o){return document.getElementById(o)};
  class Block {
   constructor(position, size, color, type) {
    this.position = position,
    this.size = size,
    this.sys = {color: color}
   }
  };

  let can = getId("can"), ctx = can.getContext('2d'), game = {
   size: 35
  },
  player = {
   position: {
    x: innerWidth / 2 - 25,
    y: innerHeight - 25 - 300
   },
   size: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50
   },
   sys: {
    color: "#AA00FF",
    velocity: {
     x: 0,
     y: 0,
     friction: .9,
     plus: 1
    },
    keys: {
     w: false,
     a: false,
     s: false,
     d: false
    },
    scroll: {
     x: 0,
     y: 0
    }
   }
  }, blocks = [], createBlock = (x, y, w, h, color) => blocks.push( new Block({x: x, y: y}, {width: w, height: h}, color)),
  collides = (pl1, pl2) => (pl1.position.x + pl1.size.width < pl2.position.x ||
   pl2.position.x + pl2.size.width < pl1.position.x ||
   pl1.position.y + pl1.size.height < pl2.position.y ||
   pl2.position.y + pl2.size.height < pl1.position.y) ? false : true,
  map = `
  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb-b
  b----------------------------b
  b----------------------------b
  b----------------------------b
  b----------------------------b
  b----------------------------b
  b-------------P--------------b
  b-------------b--------------b
  b----------------------------b
  b----------------------------b
  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
  `.trim().split('\n');

  // Тут какая-то фигня: блоки вверху "слетают" почему-то.
  for(let y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
   for(let x = 0; x < map[y].length; x++) {
    let sym = map[y][x],
    w = game.size,
    h = game.size;
    if(sym == "P") {
     player.position.x = x * w;
     player.position.y = y * h;
     player.size.width = w;
     player.size.height = h
    } else if(sym == "b") {
     createBlock(x * w, y * h, w, h, "#902")
    }
   }
  };

  onresize = () => {
   can.width = innerWidth;
   can.height = innerHeight
  };
  onresize();

  document.onkeydown = e => {
   let kc = e.keyCode;
   if(kc == 'W'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.w = true;
   if(kc == 'A'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.a = true;
   if(kc == 'S'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.s = true;
   if(kc == 'D'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.d = true;
   if(kc == 'Z'.charCodeAt()) blocks.pop()
  };
  document.onkeyup = e => {
   let kc = e.keyCode;
   if(kc == 'W'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.w = false;
   if(kc == 'A'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.a = false;
   if(kc == 'S'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.s = false;
   if(kc == 'D'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.d = false
  };
  
  (loop = () => {
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, .24903)";
   ctx.fillRect(-3e38, -3e38, 3e38 * 2, 3e38 * 2);

   // Скроллинг
   player.sys.scroll.x = -player.position.x + innerWidth / 2 - player.size.width / 2;
   player.sys.scroll.y = -player.position.y + innerHeight / 2 - player.size.height / 2;
   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(player.sys.scroll.x, player.sys.scroll.y);

   if(player.sys.keys.w) player.sys.velocity.y -= player.sys.velocity.plus;
   if(player.sys.keys.s) player.sys.velocity.y += player.sys.velocity.plus;
   if(player.sys.keys.a) player.sys.velocity.x -= player.sys.velocity.plus;
   if(player.sys.keys.d) player.sys.velocity.x += player.sys.velocity.plus;

   player.sys.velocity.y *= player.sys.velocity.friction;
   player.sys.velocity.x *= player.sys.velocity.friction;
   player.position.y += player.sys.velocity.y;
   player.position.x += player.sys.velocity.x;

   blocks.forEach(block => {
    // ВОТ ТУТ ВООБЩЕ НИЧЕГО НЕ ПОНЯТНО
    if(collides(block, player)) {
     if(player.position.y + player.size.height + player.sys.velocity.y > block.position.y) {
      player.position.y = block.position.y - block.size.height
     } else if(player.position.y - player.sys.velocity.y < block.position.y + block.size.height) {
      player.position.y = block.position.y + block.size.height
     }
    };

    ctx.fillStyle = block.sys.color;
    ctx.fillRect(block.position.x, block.position.y, block.size.width, block.size.height)
   });

   ctx.fillStyle = player.sys.color;
   ctx.fillRect(player.position.x, player.position.y, player.size.width, player.size.height);
   ctx.restore();

   requestAnimationFrame(loop)
  })();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Грубо говоря, чтобы красные блоки были твёрдыми.

Comment: А подпрыгивание которое есть сейчас это нежелательно?

Comment: Разумеется.
Просто сделать так, как в нормальных 2D играх, твёрдый блок.
Без багов, просто, коснулся игрок блока, но пройти сквозь него не может.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот, я думаю как-то так, даже кое где тверже чем хотелось бы =).

Баги с картой уровня - распечатайте содержимое строки, образующей уровень и увидите там `\t`

Добавил там Вам всякого рисования для отладки:

```js
class Block {
  constructor(position, size, color, type) {
    this.position = position,
      this.size = size,
      this.sys = {
        color: color
      }
  }
};
let debug = false;
let ctx = can.getContext('2d'),
  game = {size: 35},
  player = {
    position: {x: innerWidth / 2 - 25,y: innerHeight - 25 - 300},
    size: {width: 50, height: 50},
    sys: {
      color: "#AA00FF",
      velocity: {x: 0, y: 0,friction: .9,plus: .99},
      keys: {w: false,a: false,s: false, d: false},
      scroll: {x: 0, y: 0}
    }
  },
  blocks = [],
  createBlock = (x, y, w, h, color) => 
    blocks.push(new Block({x: x, y: y}, {width: w, height: h}, color)),
  collides = (pl1, pl2) => !(
    pl1.position.x + pl1.size.width < pl2.position.x ||
    pl2.position.x + pl2.size.width < pl1.position.x ||
    pl1.position.y + pl1.size.height < pl2.position.y ||
    pl2.position.y + pl2.size.height < pl1.position.y),
  map = `
  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb----b
  b----------------------------b
  b-------------------------bbbb
  b----------------------------b
  b----b-----------------------b
  b----------------------------b
  b-------------P--------------b
  b-------------b--------------b
  b-----------------------b----b
  b----------------------------b
  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
  `.trim().split('\t').join('').split('\n');

for (let y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < map[y].length; x++) {
    let sym = map[y][x], w = game.size,  h = game.size;
    if (sym == "P") {
      player.position.x = x * w;
      player.position.y = y * h;
      player.size.width = w;
      player.size.height = h
    } else if (sym == "b") {
      createBlock(x * w, y * h, w, h, "#902")
    }
  }
};

onresize = () => {can.width = innerWidth;can.height = innerHeight};
onresize();

document.onkeydown = e => {
  let kc = e.keyCode;
  if (kc == 'W'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.w = true;
  if (kc == 'A'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.a = true;
  if (kc == 'S'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.s = true;
  if (kc == 'D'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.d = true;
  if (kc == 'Z'.charCodeAt()) blocks.pop()
};

document.onkeyup = e => {
  let kc = e.keyCode;
  if (kc == 'W'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.w = false;
  if (kc == 'A'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.a = false;
  if (kc == 'S'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.s = false;
  if (kc == 'D'.charCodeAt()) player.sys.keys.d = false
};

(loop = () => {

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, .24903)";
  ctx.fillRect(-3e38, -3e38, 3e38 * 2, 3e38 * 2);

  // Скроллинг
  player.sys.scroll.x = -player.position.x + innerWidth / 2 - player.size.width / 2;
  player.sys.scroll.y = -player.position.y + innerHeight / 2 - player.size.height / 2;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(player.sys.scroll.x, player.sys.scroll.y);

  if (player.sys.keys.w) player.sys.velocity.y -= player.sys.velocity.plus;
  if (player.sys.keys.s) player.sys.velocity.y += player.sys.velocity.plus;
  if (player.sys.keys.a) player.sys.velocity.x -= player.sys.velocity.plus;
  if (player.sys.keys.d) player.sys.velocity.x += player.sys.velocity.plus;

  player.sys.velocity.y *= player.sys.velocity.friction;
  player.sys.velocity.x *= player.sys.velocity.friction;

  let top = null, bottom = null, left = null, right = null;
  blocks.forEach(block => {
    let a, collision = collides(block, player);
    if (collision) {
      // определяем с какой стороны стена и запоминаем ограничения
      let dy = player.position.y - block.position.y;
      let dx = player.position.x - block.position.x;
      a = Math.atan2(dy, dx)/Math.PI*180;
      if (a> 45 && a< 135) top = block.position.y+block.size.height;
      if (a<-45 && a>-135) bottom = block.position.y-player.size.height;
      if (a< 45 && a> -45) left = block.position.x+block.size.width;
      if (a>135 || a<-135) right = block.position.x-player.size.width;
    };

    ctx.fillStyle = debug && collision ? 'wheat' : block.sys.color;
    ctx.fillRect(block.position.x, block.position.y, block.size.width, block.size.height)
    if (debug && collision){
      let cx = block.position.x+block.size.width/2;
      let cy = block.position.y+block.size.height/2;
      ctx.beginPath(); 
      ctx.moveTo(cx,cy);
      ctx.lineTo(cx+Math.cos(a/180*Math.PI)*15,cy+Math.sin(a/180*Math.PI)*15);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  });
  let f = 0.66; // имитация трения об препятствия
  let fritcion = (bottom?f:1)*(top?f:1)*(left?f:1)*(right?f:1);
  player.position.y += player.sys.velocity.y * fritcion;
  player.position.x += player.sys.velocity.x * fritcion;
  
  if (bottom != null)
    player.position.y = Math.min(player.position.y, bottom);
  if (top != null)
    player.position.y = Math.max(player.position.y, top);
  if (left != null)
    player.position.x = Math.max(player.position.x, left);
  if (right != null)
    player.position.x = Math.min(player.position.x, right);
    
  ctx.fillStyle = player.sys.color;
  ctx.fillRect(player.position.x, player.position.y, player.size.width, player.size.height);
  
  if (!debug)
    return ctx.restore();
  
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  if (player.sys.velocity.y < 0 && top)
   ctx.fillRect(player.position.x, player.position.y, player.size.width, 4);
  if (player.sys.velocity.y > 0 && bottom)
   ctx.fillRect(player.position.x, player.position.y+player.size.height-4, player.size.width, 4);
  if (player.sys.velocity.x < 0 && left)
   ctx.fillRect(player.position.x, player.position.y, 4, player.size.height);
  if (player.sys.velocity.x > 0 && right)
   ctx.fillRect(player.position.x+player.size.width-4, player.position.y, 4, player.size.height); 
  
  ctx.restore();
  
})();
```

```css
body, canvas {margin: 0; display: block}
```

```html
<canvas id="can"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но есть одна проблема (баг): если прижаться к земле и начать двигаться куда-л., то ничего не выйдет (Клавиша S & A или D).
Но иногда получается двигаться и таким способом.

Ещё если прижаться к боковым стенам, такой же глюк.
То получается передвигаться, то нет.

Очень много багов, а код я почти не понял :)
Ладно, я ПОЧТИ понял как всё-таки сделать правильно.

Я просто отсчитывал столкновение от середины блока.

P.s. сейчас я этот вопрос "переопубликую", но с другим примером кода.

Comment: @H336 подправил баг, который мешал перемещаться...

Comment: Ого, да вы гений!
Спасибо огромное, но принцип работы кода мне всё равно не очень ясен, можете объяснить, если не затруднит?

Comment: @H336 какое место пояснить?

Comment: В цикле, где atan2 используется.
Даже и не догадывался, что с его помощью можно сделать ЭТО (づ◔ ͜ʖ◔)づ
Кстати, если игрок (или блок) станет другого размера, то будут баги.

Comment: @H336 да, эти углы будут работать только с квадратами, там определяется направление в сторону блока, с которым произошла коллизия и устанивливается ограничение передвижения в ту сторону, с которой найден блок...

Comment: @H336 чтобы все это работало предсказуемо можно сделать 4 области проверки коллизий, с каждой стороны по одной, и при помощи них определять ограничения, я завтра попробую :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96144/discussion-between-h-336-and-stranger-in-the-q).