# Unity: Как получить номер стороны колайдера которой он прикоснулся к другому колайдеру

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui

есть два объекта, например: два электрических проводника - два куска провода, которые имеют по два оголенных конца соответственно. На проводах есть колайдеры и мне нужно чтобы при поднесении одного оголенного конца провода к другому оголенному концу провода выводилось каким именно концом первого провода(первым концом или вторым) я соприкоснулся со вторым куском провода. Есть вроде бы свойства типо .contacts для определения точки соприкосновения, но ничего так и не вышло. Пытался сделать два бокс колайдера по одному на концах, чтобы знать каким колайдером точно прикоснулся, но не знаю как в коде идентифицировать их по отдельности. Так что надеюсь на вашу помощь.
 Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: если отталкиваться от двух коллайдеров то можно дать  им два тега. Зад и  Перед. И потом в OnCollisionEnter  проверять тег элемента с которым соприкасается

Answer (score 3):

Проще, наверное, всё таки сделать два коллайдера) если вы не хотите отлавливать касания посреди коллайдера. Можете хоть круглые для аутентичности.

Идентифицировать их очень просто) просто не нужно отлавливать одним и тем же скриптом оба коллайдера. Пишется два класса - первый вешается на конкретный коллайдер и отлавливает вхождения именно в него, а второй подписывается на первые и что-то делает исходя из того, какой именно класс отловил вхождение/выход.

```
class ColliderHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action<Collision> OnColliderEnterEvent = delegate { };

    public event Action<Collision> OnColliderExitEvent = delegate { };

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) => OnColliderEnterEvent (collision);

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision) => OnColliderExitEvent(collision);
}


class Wire : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    ColliderHandler _left;

    [SerializeField]
    ColliderHandler _right;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _left.OnColliderEnterEvent += OnLeftEnter;
        _left.OnColliderExitEvent += OnLeftExit;
        _right.OnColliderEnterEvent += OnRightEnter;
        _right.OnColliderExitEvent += OnRightExit;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        _left.OnColliderEnterEvent -= OnLeftEnter;
        _left.OnColliderExitEvent -= OnLeftExit;
        _right.OnColliderEnterEvent -= OnRightEnter;
        _right.OnColliderExitEvent -= OnRightExit;
    }

    private void OnLeftExit(Collision2D obj)
    {

    }

    private void OnLeftEnter(Collision2D obj)
    {

    }

    private void OnRightEnter(Collision2D obj)
    {

    }

    private void OnRightExit(Collision2D obj)
    {

    }
}
```

Делаете объект-родитель "Провод" ему добавляете `Wire`, объекту делаете два чайлда - "КонецПровода" и добавляете им компоненты Collider2d (или любой другой какой вам нужен) и компонент `ColliderHandler`.

Comment: я обычно такую задачу решал через угол между векторами скорости и отрезком, соединяющим центры стролкнувшихся объектов, но иногда это не тривиально

Comment: вот в этом ответе очень упрощенная реализация идеи из коммента выше https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1000159/188366

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, это точно тот ответ? А то там что-то на JS про "как сделать объект твердым"

Comment: ну это такой вопрос, а в ответе я определяю с какой стороны произошло столкновение при движении, там есть визуализация если сниппет запустить, двигать игрока - wsad, если не двигается, то надо кликнуть в область игры (она по умолчанию не в фокусе)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ну, вообще, да, прикольно) только у человека конкретная задача - если к проводу подключили другой провод - нужно понять к левому разъему его подключили или к правому. Делаем для левого разъема коллайдер и для правого. Профит. Направление здесь знать не нужно.

Comment: я это делал на юньке в vr тренажере, там надо было гайку накручивать рукой на болт, так вот в зависимости от этого угла зависел шанс, зацепится резьба или нет

Comment: Я получается создал объект провод навесил на него Wire и создал два пустых дочерния по бокам с BoxCollider и навесил на них ColliderHandler и закинул в инспекторе на Wire эти концы, и изменил в обоих скриптах везде где упоминается Collision2D на BoxCollider и в функциях OnLeftEnter OnRightEnter заставил что-нибудь вывести в консоль. Запустил потыкался концами и ничего не выводит. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Не нужно менять ни на что Collision2D, я об этом, вроде, не писал)  `void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)` - именно в таком виде Unity ищет метод, чтобы вызвать его при столкновении, если вы поменяете параметр - это будет уже совершенно другой метод и Unity его не вызовет. Почему-то решил, что у вас 2d физика. Для 3d другие методы нужны - сейчас поправлю классы

Comment: VS пишет что "Нет перегруженного метода для OnLeftEnter, OnLeftExit, OnRightEnter, OnRightExit, который соответствует делегату "Action<Collision>".

Comment: Я сделал все в 2D и использовал твой первый код и при соприкосновении у меня юнити выводит за место ответа на соприкосновение перегрузку стека: "The recuasted operation caused a stack overflow" в строке 12 "void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) => OnCollisionEnter2D(collision);"
А вот ответ на то что колайдеры больше не касаются он уже выводит!

Comment: @gwiden, эта ошибка означает, что зациклился вызов какого-то метода. Что нужно сделать? Посмотреть где метод зациклился, вам ведь даже строку указало) я случайно вызов самого метода поставил, вместо события. Вот он по кругу себя и вызывал. Поправил в коде.